# 'NULL as' returns error on creating table from query

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to create a new table from a query with new column with a NULL value for every row.

For this purpose, I use the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS SELECT _id, NULL as value, true as __deleted 
FROM test_table
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:1: Column type is unknown: value. You may need to manually clean the data at location
```

Even though the query without the table creation `SELECT _id, NULL as value, true as __deleted FROM test_table` works well.

Is my query invalid for table creation? I did not find any info about such limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check docs for [`CREATE TABLE`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/create-table.html) you will see that column type is mandatory for every column declaration, and `select typeof(null)` will return `unknown`. A possible workaround is to cast `NULL` to some data type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table AS 
SELECT _id, cast(NULL as varchar) value, true __deleted 
FROM test_table
```